# std::map with Filename as key and Filedescriptor as Value

Tags: c++, c++11

I am iterating through a vector, and each entry in the vector has to be written to a file depending on the entry.

Let's say Vector {File A, File B, File C, File A....}

So, multiple file descriptors are open and I am storing them in a `std::map`:

Key = Filename and Value = FileDescriptor. See code below.

**When a Filename is not found in the map, I insert into the map a pair of data (filename, filedescriptor). The compiler is throwing an error**. See error details below after the code.

```cpp
std::map <std::string, std::ofstream> filemap; // maintains filename for each item in the list.

std::vector <std::string> items;

for (i=0 ; i < items.size() ; i++) {

  if (keyfilemap.find(items[i]) == keyfilemap.end()) {
      std::ofstream ofs (items(i), std::ofstream::out);
      ofs << key.first << "-" << key.second << std::endl;
      // **Compiler throws an error here.**
      keyfilemap.insert(std::make_pair(filename, ofs));
        
  }
  else 
     keyfilemap[filename] << key.first << "-" << key.second << std::endl;
}
```

Compiler Error.

```
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:529:14: error: no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::basic_ofstream<char> >::pair(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, std::basic_ofstream<char>&)'
       return __pair_type(std::forward<_T1>(__x), std::forward<_T2>(__y));
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Current code seems to be incomplete with undefined symbols errors.

Comment: `std::make_pair(filename, ofs)` creates a *copy* of `ofs`. Which, as mentioned, can't be copied.

Comment: You have  filenames in the code above.  items[i], items(ii) and filename...  Which is correct?

Comment: How do I use the move? I tried below, but it didn't work.

Comment: keyfilemap.insert(std::move(std::make_pair(filename, ofs)));

Comment: @user15049375 Maybe try this `keyfilemap.insert(std::make_pair(filename, std::move(ofs)));`. You need to `std::move` the non-copy constructable argument and not the whole `make_pair()`.

Comment: awesome. Thank worked. Thank you very much

Comment: Related to that. Do you know why

Comment: for (auto const& key : keyfilemap) {
  key.second.close();
 }
 Do you know why the compiler throws an error for the key.second.close()

Comment: The simple answer to that is here: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/. `std::ofstream` class does not have a copy ctor but it has a move ctor. So objects of that type like `ofs` can only be move **constructed**. For that, you need to `std::move` them. And `make_pair` needs rvalues as its arguments. It only works with rvalues.

Comment: @user15049375 Maybe because you have written **const** in `auto const& key`. Remove the `const`. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

C++ stream classes are not copyable, but you are trying to make copies when constructing your `std::pair` for `insert()`. That is why the code is failing to compile.

You will have to either construct the `std::ofstream` objects inside the map directly, or at least transfer ownership into the map using move semantics, eg:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::ofstream> filemap;
std::vector<std::string> items;
...
for (const auto &filename : items) {
  auto iter = filemap.find(filename);
    if (iter == filemap.end()) {
        iter = filemap.emplace(filename, filename).first;
        // or:
        // iter = filemap.emplace(make_pair(filename, ofstream(filename))).first;
        // or:
        // std::ofstream ofs(filename);
        // iter = filemap.insert(std::make_pair(filename, std::move(ofs))).first; 
    }
    iter->second << key.first << "-" << key.second << std::endl;
}
```

Alternatively, just let the `std::map` default-construct the `std::ofstream` objects for you, and then you can `open()` them when needed, eg:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, std::ofstream> filemap;
std::vector<std::string> items;
...
for (const auto &filename : items) {
    auto &ofs = filemap[filename];
    if (!ofs.is_open()) {
        ofs.open(filename);
    }
    ofs << key.first << "-" << key.second << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps what you want to achieve?:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::ios_base::openmode> fname_to_fstream_pairs = {{"vacation.png", std::ofstream::out}, {"diary.txt", std::ofstream::in}};

    auto const& fname_to_fstream_pair = fname_to_fstream_pairs.find("vacation.png");

    if (fname_to_fstream_pair != std::end(fname_to_fstream_pairs))
    {
        std::ofstream ofs(fname_to_fstream_pair->first, fname_to_fstream_pair->second);
        ofs << "The vacation was great!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`std::end` denotes an element that is past the end of a container.
So, usually `it == std::end(v)` is not what you want.

PS: Oh, and you shouldn't write out to a photo that way. That was just a silly example.